# Accessing the content of <slots> in Javascript in Vue.js 2.6

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've created a simple `Button` component that I implement as follows:

```html
<Button @click="clickEvent">Download Item</Button>`
```

This is the template of my button. I use the content in `<slot>` to render its text:

```html
<div class="customButton">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

However, I need to add the slot content a second time into the `aria-label` attribute for screen readers:

```html
<div class="customButton" role="button" :aria-label="howDoIaccessSlotContent">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

How do I access the `<slot>` data? Does Vue have a special `this.$xxx` property where I can access slot information in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text content of the default slot with:

```
this.$slots.default[0].text
```

```js
const SlotComponent = {
  template: `
  <div> Value inside:
    {{ $slots.default[0].text }} - 
    {{ $slots.default[0].text }}
  </div>
  `,
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {SlotComponent},
  data: {
    val: 'foo'
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Value outside: {{val}}
  <slot-component>{{val}}</slot-component>
  <button @click="val = (val === 'foo') ? 'bar' : 'foo'">toggle</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the slots with `this.$slots`.

And you can control the rendering of the slot with a render function.

```js
export default {
  name: 'MyButton',
  render(h) {
    const rawText = this.$slots.default[0].text;
    console.log(rawText);
    return h('div', {
      attrs: {
        'aria-label': rawText
      }
    }, this.$slots.default)
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html